# Print to file unique elements of a column in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I am a pandas newbie, and can't figure out a way to print to file the elements of a pandas dataframe. Thus far, I have this:

```
df.topic.to_csv("test.txt", encoding ='utf-8')
```

Which prints to file all the elements of the topic column in my df, however, many are repeated.

```
print df['topic'].unique()
```

This one correctly prints to screen the unique elements of the topic column.
How can I print to file the unique elements of the topic column of the df?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You flagged this with `pandas`. Then, the way to go would be

```
pd.DataFrame(df['topic'].unique()).to_csv(foo, bar)
```

However, this contains some overhead. If you want it as a readable csv, have a look at [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/csv.html#csv.writer). If you just want to store it temporarily, there is, among others, [shelve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html). Finally, if you are also using numpy, have a look at [numpy.save](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html).

Comment: I defined df as my dataframe. Why do you use DataFrame?what is foo, bar??? the name of the file and the encoding? your solution does not work for me

Comment: foo, bar are you parameters... "test.txt", encoding. Since `unique()` returns a bumpy array, the quick solution is to cast that into a new data frame.